# WSO2 Identity Server and Api Manager - multiple access token in header

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

In my application I've used WSO2 Identity Server.
I've implemented some API for the user management, that call WSO2 SCIM API:
https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/6.0.0/apis/scim2-rest-apis/

The user, using the login page of the wso2 identity server, logs in my application and in return gets an access token.
To call the WSO2 SCIM APIs I've to send this access token in the request header.
Everything works fine.

Now I'm trying to use also WSO2 API Manager.
I've subscribed my application to the API in the devportal, and I got another access token.

My question is, from the frontend, when a user for example clicks on the button to add a new user, what's the best practice to send the two access token I need to call the API? The one that I need to call the api from the api manager and the one that is actually required from the wso2 scim api?

I solved the problem by giving two different names to the headers, one "Authorization" and one "Auth-apim" but I don't think it's the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

One option you could do is to register WSO2 Identity server as an external keymanager to API manager[1]. Since IS APIs can be invoked using oauth2 tokens (refer [2]), You could import the same OAuth application to APIM using the provision out-of-band OAuth key feature (refer [3]) and use the same token to invoke the APIM APIs. You could import the OAuth keys to APIM using. Please note that by default, the incoming Authorization header is dropped when the request is dispatched to the backend. You could disable it by using this config[4]

[1] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/administer/key-managers/configure-wso2is-connector/

[2] https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/6.0.0/apis/overview/#oauth-based-authentication

[3] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/api-security/oauth2/provisioning-out-of-band-oauth-clients/#step-3-provision-the-out-of-band-oauth2-client

[4] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/faq/#how-can-i-add-authentication-headers-to-messages-going-out-of-the-api-gateway-to-the-backend